# Why is matplotlib not displaying this special character correctly?

Tags: matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to display [the special character ⿱](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BF%B1) in matplotlib.

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fonts = matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
jp_fonts = [f for f in fonts if 'takao' in f.lower()]
jp_prop = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname=jp_fonts[0])
jp_prop.set_size(40)

plt.text(0.1, 0.1, '雨', fontproperties=jp_prop)
plt.text(0.1, 0.4, '風')
plt.text(0.1, 0.6, '⿱', fontproperties=jp_prop)
plt.show()
```

The third character isn't being printed correctly. It ends up as a box with an X in it (see screenshot). I don't think the font is missing that character, because in that case matplotlib seems to just output a box *without* an X in it (like for the second character, which intentionally has the font misconfigured).

[image: screenshot]

Why does this character not print correctly? My font is able to display that character without a problem in other applications.

Comment: Please note that I have no experience at all with asian languages or fonts or anything. However, my first thought based on your link would be: if this special character is not a character by itself but just the syntactic indication that two further chacters are to be renderd in a vertical alignment - what should an application print then without those two characters? Sorry if this is completely wrong...

Comment: It's a regular character in itself. It doesn't affect how other characters are aligned or displayed.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not able to understand the information of the link. Sorry again!